# use and or simultaneously in if condition Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have already created a macro like

```
If UserForm5.MultiPage1.Pages(5).Visible And UserForm5.ComboBox10 <> "A" Then

      If IsEmpty(Combobox10) Then
        MsgBox "Please FILL it", vbOKOnly, "Missing Data"
        UserForm5.MultiPage1.Value = 5
        UserForm5.ComboBox10.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
        End If
```

However I need to add another exception like b in combobox10, unless it doewnt work proper.

I have changed the code as below and it need to jump isempty section unless it doesnt.

```
If UserForm5.MultiPage1.Pages(5).Visible And (UserForm5.ComboBox10 <> "A" or UserForm5.ComboBox10 <> "B") Then

      If IsEmpty(Combobox10) Then
        MsgBox "Please FILL it", vbOKOnly, "Missing Data"
        UserForm5.MultiPage1.Value = 5
        UserForm5.ComboBox10.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
        End If
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking but `ComboBox10 <> "A"` should be `ComboBox10.Text <> "A"`.

Comment: normally, first macro works and if userform page is visible and A is chosen from combobox 10 it skips next step and user for not asking me to fill anything. however I need to add new condition to if page is visible and A or B is chosen from combobox 10 it  does not skip next step and asking me to fill. @AhmedAbdelhameed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at what `ComboBox10.Text <> "A" Or ComboBox10.Text <> "B"` would do for values "A", "B", and "C".

If ComboBox10.Text is "A" then `ComboBox10.Text <> "A"` is False and `ComboBox10.Text <> "B"` is True. That gives us `False Or True` which resolves to True.

If ComboBox10.Text is "B" then `ComboBox10.Text <> "A"` is True and `ComboBox10.Text <> "B"` is False. That gives us `True Or False` which resolves to True.

If ComboBox10.Text is "C" then `ComboBox10.Text <> "A"` is True and `ComboBox10.Text <> "B"` is True. That gives us `True Or True` which resolves to True.

So, for any valid input, that Or condition is going to return True. It could only return False for an input that was simultaneously equal to both "A" and "B".

Fixing this is simple though: just use `UserForm5.ComboBox10.Text <> "A" And UserForm5.ComboBox10.Text <> "B"`

Comment: You are so right for or function logic, however, I have changed it as your sugestion and it is aceepted for A and still asking to fill for B

Comment: The only obvious issue I see is that the comparisons would only match upper-case "A" and "B". So, if someone input "a" or "b" instead, it would cause the "Please FILL it" message to display. You can use `UCase$(ComboBox10.Text) <> "A"` etc to make sure that you are comparing an upper-case version of the text in the combo box